# Spam events appear in my Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, security, spam-prevention

In my Google Calendar, I sometimes find spam events that I never created.

In the screenshot below, you can see that they even managed to put my email address in the "Created by" field.

They are always in the past.

I could not find much information about this problem.  [This Google support tip](http://support.google.com/calendar/answer/36591?hl=en) tells me to click "Report spam", but there is no such link.

I could simply remove the event, but is there a more long-term solution?

I am using an up-to-date Firefox, on updated Ubuntu Linux, and check Google's "Activity on this account" often, so I think I can rule out the possibility of account hijacking.

[image: screen shot]

---

The spam events appear in my **main calendar** (I mean: the first one on the list, the one which does not have an "unsubscribe" link).
The sharing settings for this calendar are as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Is this on your main calendar, or a separate calendar you've created?

Comment: @AlEverett: The spam events appear in my main calendar, sorry for forgetting to mention this. I added a screenshot of the sharing settings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the answer [here](http://www.surfnetkids.com/tech/961/how-to-stop-spam-events-on-google-calendar/).

Resolution:

- In Calendar: Click the gear, select "Settings",
- Find the "Automatically add invitations to my calendar" section,
- Set its value to "No, only show invitations to which I have responded".

[image]

Comment: D'oh! Of course! Why didn't I think of that? (I've removed my incorrect guesses.)

Comment: Update 7 weeks later: I got such a spam event again! It appears that the setting got switched back to `Yes`, even though I hadn't touched it or even opened the settings page ever since.

Comment: Apparently, this is a well-known exploit and may not be fixed any time soon. [Ars Technica: How Google Calendar can be a spammer’s best friend](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/01/how-google-calendar-can-be-a-spammers-best-friend/)

Comment: I wish they had an actually useful setting, such as "Only add invitations received from people I've emailed" or "Only add invitations from my contacts"