# How do I really stop Gmail adding events to Google Calendar?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

In Google Calendar settings I have "Events from Gmail: [ ] Add automatically" unticked, because it's really annoying.

Despite this I am getting events from Gmail added automatically. Apparently from `.ics` attachments in mail from Trenitalia. How do I cause this to stop? (And does any old spam with `.ics` attachments appear in Calendar?)

Comment: I don't think any old spam with .ics attachments will appear in Calendar. Did you perhaps grant this web site access to your calendar? Or have some setting in gmail (or gmail labs) that automatically adds .ics events?

Comment: @Jerry101 Nope. Perhaps Google whitelists the sender.

Comment: I think Apple has a fix for this problem.

Comment: The Verge has an instruction list for preventing Gmailed invitations from appearing in Google Calendar. [Link to the Verge.](https://www.theverge.com/2019/8/23/20829615/google-calendar-spam-events-sharing-email-how-to-stop)

Answer (score 3):

Have you also turned off "Automatically add invitations to my calendar"?

A new annoying tactic is for spammers to send you a calendar invitation rather than an email, because this setting defaults to "yes".

[image: "Automatically add invitations to my calendar" setting option]

*Related*

- [Spam events appear in my Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/42661/88163)

Comment: Looks like it. Although the description sounds as if it still adds the invitation which everyone else sees it. Most bizarre/evil.

Comment: Aha! There's a setting in GCal. But the setting in your screenshot is for calendar-to-calendar invitations. There's a separate setting "Events from Gmail: [x] Add automatically".

Comment: @jerry101 Asker has said that he/she has already turned off that setting.